# std::Future_error when using std::promise

Tags: multithreading, c++11, promise, std-future

I'm trying to make a video player. I have added a thread to time how long a video should be show on the screen. I'm trying to decode the video and update window in the main thread; the second thread will get the packets, see how long the packet should be displayed, and send the packet to main thread then wait for time to elapse.

For some reason I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::future_error'
  what():  std::future_error: No associated state
```

What's causing the error?

My Code:

```
extern "C"{
    //FFmpeg libraries
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>

    //SDL2 libraries
    #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
}
// compatibility with newer API
#if LIBAVCODEC_VERSION_INT < AV_VERSION_INT(55,28,1)
#define av_frame_alloc avcodec_alloc_frame
#define av_frame_free avcodec_free_frame
#endif

//C++ libraries
#include <memory>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>


typedef struct PacketQueue {
    AVPacketList *first_pkt, *last_pkt;
} PacketQueue;

std::atomic<bool>           quitting;
std::mutex                  mutex;
std::condition_variable     convar;

int packet_queue_put(PacketQueue *q, AVPacket *pkt){
    AVPacketList *pkt1;
    if(av_dup_packet(pkt) < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    pkt1 = (AVPacketList*) av_malloc(sizeof(AVPacketList));
    if(!pkt1){
        return -1;
    }
    pkt1->pkt = *pkt;
    pkt1->next = NULL;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    if (!q->last_pkt){
        q->first_pkt = pkt1;
    }else{
        q->last_pkt->next = pkt1;
    }
    q->last_pkt = pkt1;
    convar.notify_all();
    return 0;
}

static int packet_queue_get(PacketQueue *q, AVPacket *pkt){
    AVPacketList *pkt1;
    int ret;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
    while(1){
        if(quitting){
            ret = -1;
            break;
        }

        pkt1 = q->first_pkt;
        if(pkt1){
            q->first_pkt = pkt1->next;
            if(!q->first_pkt){
                q->last_pkt = NULL;
            }
            *pkt = pkt1->pkt;
            av_free(pkt1);
            ret = 1;
            break;
        }else {
            convar.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

void videoTimerFunc(AVRational time_base, PacketQueue* videoq, std::promise<AVPacket> prms){
    AVPacket pkt;
    int64_t last_pts = 0;
    int64_t frameDelay;
    AVRational microseconds = {1, 1000000};

    while(!quitting){
        // Getting packet and check if there are more packets
        if(!packet_queue_get(videoq, &pkt)){
            // Close programme
            quitting = true;
        }else {
            // Send packet and create timer
            frameDelay = av_rescale_q(pkt.dts, time_base, microseconds) - last_pts;
            last_pts = av_rescale_q(pkt.dts, time_base, microseconds);
            prms.set_value(pkt);

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(frameDelay));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
AVFormatContext*                FormatCtx = nullptr;
AVCodecContext*                 CodecCtxOrig = nullptr;
AVCodecContext*                 CodecCtx = nullptr;
AVCodec*                        Codec = nullptr;
int                             videoStream;
AVFrame*                        Frame = nullptr;
AVPacket                        packet;
struct SwsContext*              SwsCtx = nullptr;

PacketQueue                     videoq;
std::promise<AVPacket>          pktprms;
std::future<AVPacket>           pktftr = pktprms.get_future();
int                             frameFinished;
int64_t                         lastPTS;

SDL_Event                       event;
SDL_Window*                     screen;
SDL_Renderer*                   renderer;
SDL_Texture*                    texture;
std::shared_ptr<Uint8>          yPlane, uPlane, vPlane;
int                             uvPitch;

if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
}

// Register all formats and codecs
av_register_all();

// Initialise SDL2
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initialise SDL - %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return -1;
}

// Setting things up
quitting = false;
memset(&videoq, 0, sizeof(PacketQueue));

// Open video file
if(avformat_open_input(&FormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL) != 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file\n");        
    return -1; // Couldn't open file
}

// Retrieve stream information
if(avformat_find_stream_info(FormatCtx, NULL) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find stream information\n");

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&FormatCtx);

    return -1; // Couldn't find stream information
}

// Find the video stream
videoStream = av_find_best_stream(FormatCtx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, NULL, 0);
if(videoStream < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find video stream\n");

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&FormatCtx);

    return -1; // Didn't find a video stream
}

// Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
CodecCtxOrig = FormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;

// Find the decoder for the video stream
Codec = avcodec_find_decoder(CodecCtxOrig->codec_id);
if(Codec == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec\n");

    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(CodecCtxOrig);

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&FormatCtx);

    return -1; // Codec not found
}

// Copy context
CodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(Codec);
if(avcodec_copy_context(CodecCtx, CodecCtxOrig) != 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't copy codec context");

    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(CodecCtxOrig);

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&FormatCtx);

    return -1; // Error copying codec context
}

// Open codec
if(avcodec_open2(CodecCtx, Codec, NULL) < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open codec\n");

    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(CodecCtx);
    avcodec_close(CodecCtxOrig);

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&FormatCtx);
    return -1; // Could not open codec
}

// Allocate video frame
Frame = av_frame_alloc();

// Make a screen to put our video
screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Video Player", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, CodecCtx->width, CodecCtx->height, 0);
if(!screen){
    fprintf(stderr, "SDL: could not create window - exiting\n");
    quitting = true;

    // Clean up SDL2
    SDL_Quit();

    // Free the YUV frame
    av_frame_free(&Frame);

    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(CodecCtx);
    avcodec_close(CodecCtxOrig);

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&FormatCtx);

    return -1;
}

renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen, -1, 0);
if(!renderer){
    fprintf(stderr, "SDL: could not create renderer - exiting\n");
    quitting = true;

    // Clean up SDL2
    SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);
    SDL_Quit();

    // Free the YUV frame
    av_frame_free(&Frame);

    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(CodecCtx);
    avcodec_close(CodecCtxOrig);

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&FormatCtx);
    return -1;
}

// Allocate a place to put our YUV image on that screen
texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_YV12, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, CodecCtx->width, CodecCtx->height);
if(!texture){
    fprintf(stderr, "SDL: could not create texture - exiting\n");
    quitting = true;

    // Clean up SDL2
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);
    SDL_Quit();

    // Free the YUV frame
    av_frame_free(&Frame);

    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(CodecCtx);
    avcodec_close(CodecCtxOrig);

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&FormatCtx);
    return -1;
}

// Initialise SWS context for software scaling
SwsCtx = sws_getContext(CodecCtx->width, CodecCtx->height, CodecCtx->pix_fmt,
            CodecCtx->width, CodecCtx->height, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if(!SwsCtx){
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't create sws context\n");
    quitting = true;

    // Clean up SDL2
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);
    SDL_Quit();

    // Free the YUV frame
    av_frame_free(&Frame);

    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(CodecCtx);
    avcodec_close(CodecCtxOrig);

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&FormatCtx);
    return -1;
}

// set up YV12 pixel array (12 bits per pixel)
yPlane = std::shared_ptr<Uint8>((Uint8 *)::operator new (CodecCtx->width * CodecCtx->height, std::nothrow));
uPlane = std::shared_ptr<Uint8>((Uint8 *)::operator new (CodecCtx->width * CodecCtx->height / 4, std::nothrow));
vPlane = std::shared_ptr<Uint8>((Uint8 *)::operator new (CodecCtx->width * CodecCtx->height / 4, std::nothrow));
uvPitch = CodecCtx->width / 2;

if (!yPlane || !uPlane || !vPlane) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate pixel buffers - exiting\n");
    quitting = true;

    // Clean up SDL2
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);
    SDL_Quit();

    // Free the YUV frame
    av_frame_free(&Frame);

    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(CodecCtx);
    avcodec_close(CodecCtxOrig);

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&FormatCtx);
    return -1;
}

std::thread videoTimerThread(videoTimerFunc, FormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->time_base, &videoq, std::move(pktprms));

while (!quitting) {
    // Check for more packets
    if(av_read_frame(FormatCtx, &packet) >= 0){
        // Check what stream it belongs to
        if (packet.stream_index == videoStream) {
            packet_queue_put(&videoq, &packet);
        }else{
            // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
            av_free_packet(&packet);
        }
    }

    // Check if its time to update
    if(pktftr.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) == std::future_status::ready){
        // Getting packet
        packet = pktftr.get();

        // Decode video frame
        avcodec_decode_video2(CodecCtx, Frame, &frameFinished, &packet);

        // Did we get a video frame?
        if (frameFinished) {
            AVPicture pict;
            pict.data[0] = yPlane.get();
            pict.data[1] = uPlane.get();
            pict.data[2] = vPlane.get();
            pict.linesize[0] = CodecCtx->width;
            pict.linesize[1] = uvPitch;
            pict.linesize[2] = uvPitch;

            // Convert the image into YUV format that SDL uses
            sws_scale(SwsCtx, (uint8_t const * const *) Frame->data, Frame->linesize, 0, CodecCtx->height, pict.data, pict.linesize);

            SDL_UpdateYUVTexture(texture, NULL, yPlane.get(), CodecCtx->width, uPlane.get(), uvPitch, vPlane.get(), uvPitch);

            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }
        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
        av_free_packet(&packet);
    }

    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            quitting = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

videoTimerThread.join();

//SDL2 clean up
SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);
SDL_Quit();

// Free the YUV frame
av_frame_free(&Frame);

// Free Sws
sws_freeContext(SwsCtx);

// Close the codec
avcodec_close(CodecCtx);
avcodec_close(CodecCtxOrig);

// Close the video file
avformat_close_input(&FormatCtx);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::future` is one-shot. Once you called `get()`, it's in invalid state, and any further `wait*()` or `get()` calls on it exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: So the problem is to do with the `ptkftr.get()` and `ptkftr.wait_for()`?

Comment: The problem is to do with your attempt to use `std::promise` and `std::future` in a loop. They don't work that way; they can communicate exactly one value, once.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik How can I get around this and where does it say it's an issue in cppreference?

Comment: [`std::future::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get): *"The behavior is undefined if `valid()` is `false` before the call to this function. Any shared state is released. `valid()` is `false` after a call to this method."*

Comment: As to how you can solve this: don't use `promise` and `future` for things they weren't meant to do. Beyond this, I don't understand your problem well enough to design a solution. At first glance, it seems you need a producer-consumer queue. And you even seem to have one, and use it in one place; it's not clear why you are trying to invent a different mechanism for that other place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `std::promise` and `std::future` in a loop. Thanks to Igor Tandetnik, for commenting that.